# Use a LookUp field in a Calculated Column

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, lookup-column, calculated-column

I have a SP2013 Server but have not been authorized to install SPD2013. I have a list [Web Team Tasker] which has a lookup column containing data from a list on a parent site as well as some subcolumns associated with the lookup column. I would like to on of the subcolumns in a calculated field. Would anyone be able to walk me through the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First,** you should be aware of the `Lookup columns` cannot be referenced in a calculated column formula.

> Check **[The Supported and Unsupported Columns in SharePoint Calculated Column Formula.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)**

---

**Workarounds:**

What do you mean with "*`you aren't authorized to install SharePoint designer?`*" Do you mean you can't install it on the SP server?!

Actually, you don't need to install SP Designer on the SP server, instead, install it on your PC then connect to your SharePoint site.

**So if you have SharePoint designer, you can simply**

- Create a workflow that copies the lookup column value to another column with a text data type.
- Then use this field value in your calculated column formula.

> Check the detail steps at **[How to use Lookup field in SharePoint Calculated Column Formula.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/lookup-field-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)**

---

**Note:** if you have a piece of programming knowledge, and you can't use SharePoint designer. So, you can create an **[event receiver](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/lookup-field-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/#using-sharepoint-event-receiver)** on item added and updated action to

- Achieve the same behavior by copying the lookup column value to another column with a text data type then reference the text column in a calculated column formula.
- Build your formula by code and save it to a field instead of using the calculated column.

Comment: I have SPD 2010 and the site 2013. But I will try your work around.

Comment: Do you have any issue to install SP2013 beside SP2010, If yes try to use JSOM to build your formula as mentioned at **[Auto Populate Field Values based on Lookup Selection In SharePoint.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/autofill-list-form-fields-based-on-lookup-selection-in-sharepoint/)** :) Good Luck

Comment: I don't administer the network I don't control what gets installed on the machines or not

Comment: Thank you. The workflow idea pointed me in the right direction. I used NinTex Workflow as the hosting facility disabled OOB workflows.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calculated column using your other columns in a formula, then create a new column that is a lookup to the calculated column. it works, have it in my InfoPath form.

Comment: This is in use with a 2010 InfoPath form hosted now in SharePoint Online, using InfoPath 2013 to slide the new lookup field into the form