# Render one or another column only if data is present?

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I'm a relative newbie working on SP2013 w/o SPD. I have a lookup column for `NAMEPD` and a text column for `NAME NOT FOUND` on the same list. `NAMEPD` is a simple dropdown choice, `NAME NOT FOUND` is there for the user to input a name in case one is not in the `NAMEPD`. Is there a calculated column method for displaying the data from either of these columns if data is present?

I have creating a calculated column named NAME1 with the formula `=[NAMEPD]&" "&[NAME NOT FOUND]` but get the following error:

> "One or more column references are not allowed, because the columns
>   are defined as a data type that is not supported in formulas."

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you are not allowed to reference Lookup Fields in Calculated Columns (w/o SPD). Details can be found in

[Use a LookUp field in a Calculated Column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/208332/use-a-lookup-field-in-a-calculated-column/208352#208352)

You can definitely accomplish this with SPD and a simple workflow if you'd like (this process is mentioned in the answer).

Comment: Could I use JavaScript in a CEWP to accomplish this render?

Comment: I believe you could, the problem being that you can't reference the field elsewhere in SharePoint.